# OpenGL quad strip not showing

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw 2 Quad_Strips on top of each other, but I can't see one of them when its rotated on top of the other.

Here is a picture of what I'm talking about:

Both quads side by side

[image: 1]

Rotated so the blue one is on top

[image: 2]

Rotated so the green one is on top

[image: 3]

Why is it that the green quad is "see-through" when it should be on top?

Comment: does `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK);` fix it? If it does then you've got a problem with backface culling and need to draw the verticies of the quad in the opposite order. If not then try drawing the two quads in the opposite order and seeing if the behaviour changes. If it does then it might be an issue with the precision of the depth buffer.

Comment: I tried drawing the vertices in reverse order, but that didn't seem to do anything.  Drawing them in reverse order did make the blue quad the "see-through" one though

Comment: Actually now that you mention it, I am drawing the vertices of each quad in an 'X' pattern, maybe that is the problem

Comment: An X pattern will definitely do weird and wonderful things. By default you want to specify the vertices in counter clockwise order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably forgot to enable depth testing. Without that things are overdraw each other in the order they are sent to OpenGL. Solution

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

right before the code drawing the quad strips.